# Intermittent failed SQL Server logins with Windows Auth/trusted - Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'

Tags: sql-server, wcf

Also found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/1002346f-abb9-444d-88e2-b381938ad6d1

We are using .NET 4.0 with autofac, nHibernate 3.1 with Fluent nHibernate 1.2. We have a WCF application hosted in IIS7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 and SQL Server 2008. We are experiencing intermittent login failures in production; some may be under load, some are definitely not under any kind of load. We are configured for IIS Windows Auth and SQL Server trusted authentication, and a majority of the time, the service account configured for the IIS app pool authenticates as expected, but intermittently we receive failed login messages for the machine name instead of the service account:

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while 
executing a resolve operation. See the InnerException for details. 

---> FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or 
incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. 
Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'.

... trimmed less relevant parts of error message ...
```

Comment: If it's intermittent, is it possible the domain controller (or the connection to the domain controller) is flaky?

Comment: But the failure is of the machine account, which should not be used. There is a service account that spans machines that should be used, and when it is used, authenticates successfully. Windows Auth in IIS with a service account for the app pool identity, trusted security in connection string -- the machine name should never be part of the equation.

Comment: Is the machine in a domain? I'm not a huge auth guy but it may very well be the case that the domain is checked before local.

Comment: @andrewbadera - the machine account is used if the IIS app pool identity is ran as NetworkService FYI

Comment: Aaron, yes, the machine is in a domain -- note DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$. The controller is on the same physical network, possibly the same subnet, as the app server.

Comment: Quantum Elf - you'll note I mention the app pool is configured to use a specific service account, which works most of the time. The machine name login failure is intermittent, and unexpected due to using a specific, custmo service principal for the app pool

Comment: Does the intermittent behavior occur more frequently at certain times of the day?  Also I wonder if it has to do with Domain Controller replication activities?